# How does Kotlin property access syntax work for Java classes (i.e. EditText setText)?

Tags: android, android-edittext, kotlin

I'm trying to switch my Android project to Kotlin. I have an `EditText` (a subclass of `TextView`) for which I want to set a hint and text programmatically. The hint works as expected. For text, though, I'm getting a type mismatch exception if I try to do it using Kotlin setter syntax:

```
    val test = EditText(context)

    test.setHint("hint")    // Lint message: "Use property access syntax"
    test.hint = "hint"      // ok

    test.setText("text")    // ok (no lint message)
    test.text = "text"      // Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.String but android.text.Editable! was expected
```

If we look at the declaration, we'll find identical signatures inherited from `TextView`:

```
    public final void setHint(CharSequence hint)

    public final void setText(CharSequence text)
```

I had an impression that `x.y = z` was a shortcut for `x.setY(z)` but apparently that impression was wrong. `setText()` is treated as a normal method rather than a setter, but what's the difference between these two methods that makes the compiler behave differently? The only one I can think of is that `TextView` has an `mHint` property but I don't think it might be the case.

Another thing I don't quite understand is, where does `android.text.Editable` come from? There is no corresponding `setText(Editable)` method, nor is there a public field of this type.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

When generating a synthetic property for a Java getter/setter pair Kotlin first looks for a getter. The getter is enough to create a synthetic property with a type of the getter. On the other hand the property will not be created if only a setter presents.

When a setter comes into play property creation becomes more difficult. The reason is that the getter and the setter may have different type. Moreover, the getter and/or the setter may be overridden in a subclass.

In your case the `TextView` class contains a getter `CharSequence getText()` and a setter `void setText(CharSequence)`. If you had a variable of type `TextView` your code would work fine. But you have a variable of type `EditText`. And the `EditText` class contains an overridden getter `Editable getText()`, which means that you can get an `Editable` for an `EditText` and set an `Editable` to an `EditText`. Therefore, Kotlin reasonably creates a synthetic property `text` of type `Editable`. The `String` class is not `Editable`, that's why you cannot assign a `String` instance to the `text` property of the `EditText` class.

Comment: Nice explanation, sir.

Comment: When calling java from Kotlin, I'd say the linter isn't really doing you a favor suggesting you use the synthetic property.  1) It's not at all obvious when you can use it (as the OP's example illustrates)  2) Because sometimes you can and sometimes you can't use it you end up with two different coding styles for similar looking operations  3)  The documentation is in the Java notation.      I just turn that inspection off.

Comment: Then how can I get the text from interface callback . I wanted to set the dialog selected text to edittext.

Answer (score 19):

To avoid type mismatch, you can use the Factory inner class of Editable class. 
So you can do now something like:

```
textview.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("your text")
```

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively you could write an extension:

```
fun String.toEditable(): Editable =  Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(this)
```

You can then use it as such:

```
mEditText.text = myString.toEditable()
```

Answer (score 5):

The `android.text.Editable` comes from the [`getText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()). It appears to me that the `obj.text = value` resolution in Kotlin is 2 step process.

1. Compiler tries to finds a `text` property or Java method `getText` from which it infers the property type
2. For the inferred property type the compiler tries to find corresponding property setter or Java method `setText(PropertyType value)`

Since in the 1. the inferred type is `Editable` the `editText.text = "value"` fails with `Type mismatch` error.