# Setting text in EditText Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I am trying to set text in a EditText but it says:

```
Type mismatch. 
Required: Editable 
Found: String
```

My code is as follow:

```
String name = "Paramjeet"
val nametxt = findViewById (R.id.nametxt) as EditText
nametxt.text = name
```

Don't say to use `setText` because I am using kotlin, not Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Kotlin property access syntax work for Java classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374075/how-does-kotlin-property-access-syntax-work-for-java-classes)

Comment: Aside: You don't need findViewById if you use the Kotlin Android extensions (shipped with Android Studio). You should just be able to call `nexttxt.setText(name)` without any find or casting.

Comment: This is not a Kotlin code as you are claiming @Singh

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko:  Yeah, we should remove this thread because everyone who can't set text in their kotlin EditText would immediately think to search for "kotlin property access syntax for java classes."  It's the first thing that popped up in my head when I saw that compiler error.

Answer (score 533, accepted):

Use `setText(String)`, since `editText.text` expects an `Editable`, not a `String`.

Comment: nither EditText get focus after setText() nor softInput keyboard open

Comment: But why? It sounds so similar!!

Comment: So much for Kotlin's desire to avoid java's property use syntax!  Yup, setter method thrown right out the window!

Comment: @SMBiggs so much for java fanboying over Kotlin's ease of, well, everything.

Comment: @SMBiggs haha maybe you did, cuz I'm deeply in love with Kotlin. Good day mate!

Comment: is there any documentation for this?

Comment: @LeJexy https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText#setText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType) this quite possibly is what you are asking for

Answer (score 53):

Use `setText(String)` as `EditText.text` requires an `editable` at firstplace not String

**WHY ?**

[Nice explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37374301/4079010) by **Michael** given under [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37374301/4079010). Do visit this link for more detail

When generating a synthetic property for a Java getter/setter pair Kotlin first looks for a getter. The getter is enough to create a synthetic property with a type of the getter. On the other hand the property will not be created if only a setter presents.

When a setter comes into play property creation becomes more difficult. The reason is that the getter and the setter may have different type. Moreover, the getter and/or the setter may be overridden in a subclass.

Answer (score 47):

There are several working answers here, but if you still want to use the property format and have your code look clean, you could write an extension:

```
fun String.toEditable(): Editable =  Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(this)
```

You can then use it as such:

```
mEditText.text = myString.toEditable()
```

Comment: Extension approach is better than using old java setText.

Comment: Better do extension for edit text :   


fun EditText.setEditableText(text:String){ this.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(text) }

Answer (score 28):

**Simple Solution**

Just use `edittext.setText(yourdata`) instead of `edittext.text` because the *EditText* is editable, the `edittext.text` is used for `TextView`

**For Example:**

```
var name:String = "Muzammil"
edittext.setText(name)
```

That's it its work for me.

Comment: Slightly better explanation than nhaarman's answer.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to use getter `.text` from principle, use:

```
nametxt.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(name)
```

Answer (score 10):

Or **cast** to `TextView` but I believe this should be fixed on kotlin side for sure for convenience of developers !

```
(someEditText as TextView).text = "someTextValue"
```

Or with some extensions:

```
val EditText.asTextView: TextView get() = this as TextView

var EditText.value: CharSequence? 
    get() = asTextView.text
    set(value) {
        asTextView.text = value
    }
```

You can write:

```
someEditText.asTextView.text = "someTextValue"
```

or

```
someEditText.value = "someTextValue"
```

But sadly you just **cannot** **write** simple `someEditText.text = "someTextValue"`

Comment: Why was this down-voted?  Seems as perfectly reasonable as anything else in Kotlin.

Comment: @SMBiggs maybe too much similar answers, I am just guessing as this was mine haha

Comment: OR use someEditText.setText("new value") instead of setting the text property.

Comment: Maybe because android.widget.EditText has a .text property but does not have .asTextView nor .value properties?

Answer (score 8):

Or you can use an extension property:

```
var EditText.value
    get() = this.text.toString()
    set(value) {
            this.setText(value)
    }
```

and use `.value=` instead of `.text=`

Answer (score 3):

Methods that follow the Java conventions for getters and setters (no-argument methods with names starting with get and single-argument methods with names starting with set) are represented as properties in Kotlin.
 But, While generating a property for a Java getter/setter pair Kotlin at first looks for a getter. The getter is enough to infer the type of property from the type of the getter. On the other hand, the property will not be created if only a setter is present( because Kotlin does not support set-only properties at this time ) .

When a setter comes into play, property generation process becomes a bit ambiguous. The reason is that the getter and the setter may have different type. Moreover, the getter and/or the setter may be overridden in a subclass ,
 which exactly is the case of EditText in android.

In above case the Android TextView class contains a getter

```
CharSequence getText()
```

and a setter void

```
setText(CharSequence)
```

If I had a variable of type TextView my code would have worked fine.
 But I used EditText class which contains an overridden getter

```
Editable getText()
```

which means that you can get an Editable for an EditText and set an Editable to an EditText. Therefore, Kotlin reasonably creates a synthetic property text of type Editable. As String class is not Editable, that’s why I cannot assign a String instance to the text property of the EditText class.

It Seems like JetBrains forgot to specify the dominant role of getter methods while generating kotlin properties for Java getter and setter methods. Anyways, I have submitted pull request to Jet brains kotlin website through github.

I have detailed above problem in this medium post too [How Does Kotlin Generate Property from Java Getters and Setters (Undocumented by Jetbrains)](https://medium.com/@er.abhishek.luthra/how-does-kotlin-generated-property-from-java-getters-and-setters-undocumented-by-jetbrains-7e1ad88052b1)

Answer (score 2):

Use like this:

```
edtTitle.setText(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE))
edtDesc.setText(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_DESC))
```

Answer (score 2):

```kotlin
val editable = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(savedString)

editText.text = editable
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in my projects, I give you an example that shows how to retrieve and set data in the layouts using Kotlin:
there is one button `save_button` and two text edit field `edit_name` and `edit_password`.

```
 //when cliquing on the button 'save_button' 
    save_button.setOnClickListener {
    // geting the value from the two fields by using .text.toString()
                val email =  edit_name.text.toString()
                val password = edit_password.text.toString()
    // showing the result on the systeme's log 
                    Log.d("Main activity","your email is " + email )
                    Log.d("Main activity", "your password is $password" )
    // Then shows these values into the text view palete using  .setText()
                    text_view.setText("$email " + "$password")
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

setText(String), so you must setText your string to editText, so in your case is : **nametxt.setText(name)**

Answer (score -2):

```kotlin
var name:String = "hello world"

textview.text = name
```

(or)

```kotlin
var editText:String = "hello world"

textview.setText(name)
```

Comment: Please, use code blocks for share your code

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old, well answered question, please explain how it complements all other answers.

Answer (score -4):

Look at the API of EditText:

`void setText (CharSequence text, TextView.BufferType type)`

`Editable getText ()`

Link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

Answer (score -6):

Try using nametxt.post: **nametxt.post({nametxt.setText("your text")})**