# type mismatch required:Editabel Found:String

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

### I am new to programming so any help would be appreciated

```
buFindAge.setOnClickListener {
val YearOfBirth:Int=txtYearOfBirth.toString().toInt()
val myAge:Int=2018-YearOfBirth
 tvShowAge.text=myAge.toString()
 tvShowAge.text="$myAge"  // Same error
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting text in EditText Kotlin,Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493908/setting-text-in-edittext-kotlin-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.setText()` instead of `text=`

Comment: It worked thanks, but can you explain why it was giving me an error when using text=

Comment: There is a duplicate where you can find the complete explanation posted before  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493908/setting-text-in-edittext-kotlin-android

Answer (score 0):

**Main Activity**

```
val rollno = deleteDialog.enterrollnoID.text.toString().trim()
mainViewModel.addUser(UserData(rollNo = rollno.toInt()))
```

**Adapter**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DataVHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.rollnoText.text= dataList[position].rollNo.toString()
}
override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataList.size
inner class DataVHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val rollnoText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rollNoTextID) as TextView
}
```