# How to post text to a text box insted of a toast?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-toast, google-mlkit

Hey there people I'm new to Android and Kotlin can you help me with this please.

```
recognizer.recognize(ink)
            .addOnSuccessListener { result: RecognitionResult ->
                Toast.makeText(context, "I see ${result.candidates[0].text}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }
```

here the results is posted to a toast and I want it to be in a text box how to do that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting text in EditText Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493908/setting-text-in-edittext-kotlin)

Comment: instead of Toast.makeText() should i use text_view.setText("${result.candidates[0].text}").    here text_view being the name of my text field?

Comment: Yes exactly. The text view should be declared in your XML layout.

Comment: thank you nicolas and I don't need to do anything in main activity right

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define a TextView in your layout file and then setText(...) with the detection result you get in onSuccessListener.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SnackBar. Add this to your code:

```
    fun showSnackBar(message: String) {
    val snackBar =
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), message, 
    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    val snackBarView = snackBar.view
    snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(
        ContextCompat.getColor(
            this@BaseActivity,
            R.color.PUTCOLORHERE
        )
    )
    snackBar.show()
}
```

You could replace your toast like this:

```
recognizer.recognize(ink)
        .addOnSuccessListener { result: RecognitionResult ->
          showSnackBar("PUT WORDS HERE")
        }
```