# How do I set the text of an EditText to an Int?

Tags: android, string, kotlin, int

In an attempt to set an `EditText` to an `Int` value, I've tried various ways of converting the `Int` to a value that the `EditText` will accept, but all fail:

```
   processButton.setOnClickListener {
        var intNo = inputText.text as Int
        intNo *= 2
        outputText.text = intNo as String       // error = "required editable"
        outputText.text = intNo.toString()      // err: type mismatch 
        outputText.text = Int.toString(intNo)   // type mismatch reqd editable
        outputText.text = "What is going on?"   // type mismatch reqd editable
    }
```

How can I set the `EditText` to an `Int` value?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374075/how-does-kotlin-property-access-syntax-work-for-java-classes-i-e-edittext-sett

Answer (score 18):

```
 var a: Int = 12
 var s: String = a.toString()
```

This should work for this.

Comment: No, Rajesh's solution is the one that works because in Android the textViews are EditText not Strings.

Answer (score 6):

Try given code it will work. What I am doing here I am converting inputText first to String then Int. After I am multiplying with 2 then I am assigning a value for outputText by converting to string.

```
processButton.setOnClickListener {

    var intNo  = inputText.text.toString().toInt()
    intNo *= 2
    //println(intNo.toString())
    val myString = intNo.toString()
    // If you using outputText as Editable then use this
    outputText.text = SpannableStringBuilder(myString)

    }
```

Comment: @CarltonMcDonald outputText.text ? is TextView or EditText ?

Comment: Accept this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple things going on here, and to understand them, let's take a look at the various `getText` and `setText` methods that `EditText` has:

```
Editable getText()
void setText(CharSequence text)
void setText(@StringRes int resid)
// many other setText methods with buffer options
```

So what Kotlin does here to let you use property syntax is that it creates a `text` property. The getter used for the property is obvious, since there's only one. The setter for the property is *supposed to be* the one that takes a `CharSequence` parameter (it would make sense, `Editable` extends `CharSequence`), but actually trying to assign anything other than an `Editable` to it won't work. See [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9313).

---

To get to the problem at hand, you can read the value in your `EditText` and convert it to a `String` like this:

```
val input = inputText.text.toString()
```

Then, you can use the `toInt()` function from the standard library to convert it to an `Int` (be aware that this will throw an exception if the `String` can't be parsed):

```
val doubled = input.toInt() * 2
```

And finally, you can set the value of the `EditText` by calling the `setText` setter in the traditional Java style, passing in a `String`:

```
inputText.text.setText(doubled.toString())
```

A bit of a mess because of the two-way conversion between `String` and `Int`, plus the oddities of how the `text` property is generated here, but that's the way to do it. If you're bothered by how this looks, you could always hide some of this mechanism behind extension properties.

Comment: The following compiles but when processButton clicked it crashes:

processButton.setOnClickListener {
            var intNo = inputText.text.toString().toInt()
            intNo *= 2
            outputText.text = intNo as Editable 
        }

Comment: You won't be able to cast `intNo` to an `Editable`. Instead, use the code I provided in my answer to convert your number back to a `String`, and then use `setText`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var num: Int = 5
```

to convert to string would be

```
num.toString()
```