# I get a "Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Editable! was expected" I used this same code down below and it works?

Tags: kotlin

```
override fun update(message: String) {
    var text = textViewInstructions.text.toString()

    val timer = object : CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            textViewInstructions.setText(newText)
            textViewInstructions.setSelection(textViewInstructions.text.length)
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            textViewInstructions.text = ""  // this line here ??
        }
    }
    timer.start()
}
```

Comment: What's the type of `newText`? Is it also a string?

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Comment: override fun update(message: String) {
            var text = textViewInstructions.text.toString()
            var newText = """
            $text
            $message
            """

Comment: textViewInstructions.setText(newText)
            textViewInstructions.setSelection(textViewInstructions.text.length)

        val timer = object : CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            textViewInstructions.setText(newText)
            textViewInstructions.setSelection(textViewInstructions.text.length)
            }

Comment: override fun onFinish() {
                textViewInstructions.text = ""  // this line here ??
            }
        }
        timer.start()
    }

Comment: the last 3 comments is the code, there was a part left out sorry

Comment: i am very new at this, all I know is I have the same timer working in a different spot of code

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In this case of `EditText`, You need to use

```
textViewInstructions.setText("")
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374075/how-does-kotlin-property-access-syntax-work-for-java-classes-i-e-edittext-sett)