# how to pass data to MaterialAlertDialogBuilder in android

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog

I'm using latest material design library. Now to create a custom dialog I'm doing this

```
holder.id_edit_srt_bit.setOnClickListener {
            println(my_data[position])
            var data = my_data[position]

            MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
                .setView(R.layout.dialog_edit_form)
                .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which ->
                    println("---------> $dialog -> $which")
                }
                .setNegativeButton("NO") { dialog, which ->
                    println("---------> $dialog -> $which")
                }
                .show()
        }
```

on click it is opening the dialog with my custom layout `dialog_edit_form`. it has two text fields with `id1` and `id2`.

now when opening this dialog i need to set a value which is in `data` variable

how to do that ?

i tried this but its not working

```
            var dialog = Dialog(context)
            dialog.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.id1)?.text = data?.val1 as Editable
            dialog.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.id2)?.text = data?.val2 as Editable
```

please answer in material design way only. I don't want older ways of doing it That's why i'm using `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to do like this

```
var dialogView = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
    .setView(R.layout.dialog_edit_form)
    ...
    .show()

    dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.id1)?.text =
                Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("${data?.val1}")
   
    dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.id2)?.text =
                Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("${data?.val2}")
```

in order To avoid type mismatch, you can use the Factory inner class of Editable class.

`Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("your_text_value")`

more details on type mismatch is available here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37374301/13074527